# Get the DocumentText of a webBrowser after form submission

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I have a C# application to fill and submit a form automatically in a `WebBrowser`, then return me the `DocumentText` after the form is submitted and processed on the server, I tried this code, but the i am getting the  `DocumentText` before the form submission.

```
private String afterform()
    {
        String toreturnstring = "";
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        HtmlElement theform= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("theform");
        theform.InvokeMember("Submit");


        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        toreturnstring = webBrowser1.DocumentText;  
        return toreturnstring;

    }
```

**Note:** I see the form target page opened already after the `toreturnstring` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because you are getting the DocumentText way too soon.  DocumentText is not necessarily set when the WebBrowsers state returns to Complete.

According to MSDN:

> If you set the value of this property and then immediately retrieve
>   it again, the value retrieved may be different than the value set if
>   the WebBrowser control has not had time to load the new content. You
>   can retrieve the new value in a DocumentCompleted event handler.
>   Alternatively, you can block the thread until the document is loaded
>   by calling the Thread.Sleep method in a loop until the DocumentText
>   property returns the value that you originally set it to.

While in this case we are not directly setting the value of DocumentText, I still wanted to do a quick test to see if the change occurs on page navigation.  After the test and noticed that DocumentTest was still not set by the time the DocumentCompleted event handler was called.

I created another event that (a button) could happen sometime after the page url changed.  I then inspected the DocumentText and it was changed to the new page.  Also tried with the thread.sleep as MSDN suggested and it works.

I hope this helps.

```
public string NewDocumentTextForMeToPlayWith{ get; set; }

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    NewDocumentTextForMeToPlayWith = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement theform = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    theform.InvokeMember("Submit");
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);


}
```